Inbox pattern and outbox pattern
I don't see the difference between the Inbox pattern and the Outbox pattern.
the Inbox pattern saves messages in a database. The Outbox pattern too, so what is the difference?

Actually it's very good question.
There are some differences which we should take consider. For first we got 3 approaches to delivery messages:

At most once - You deliver it max 1 times
At least once - You deliver message at least one time
Exactly one

Outbox pattern and inbox pattern descirbes "at least once" strategy. Let's have a look for real live example when You got API-one, message broker and API-two, so two microservices with message broker.

Request comes API-one
Your business logic starts work and probably it will be ended by something like that :


save entity to DB and after this saving, send event to broker.

What is a problem here? If entity will be saved to DB and for some reason after that BUT BEFORE send event your api will die, API-two will be not informed about that operation, and Your data will be inconsistent.
Outbox pattern:

Request comes to API-one
Business logic is proceed
You come to end part and You SAVE ENTITY AND EVENT to DB in one transaction, but to DB in API-one microservice. Then some background job or whatever will look to API-one DB and check event table. It will take that event and push to broker. Then broker will eventually send You ACK  of transaction and Your job will remove this event from events table.
Meanwhile API-two listen to broker and if message will be delivered to API-two it will proceed own business logic.

Inbox pattern
In inbox pattern situation is little bit different but very similar

API-one publish event to BUS 
API-two RECIVES an event and SAVE IT TO API-two DB
Then some job is looking for example every 5 second into API-two DB events table and proceed every of them

To sum up -
Outbox pattern - You store events into DB of API-one 
Inbox patter - You store events into DB of API-two 
Main difference is that Outbox is for OUTCOME and Income is for processing incoming messages
